# Set comprehensions don't work on Pydev (Python)

Tags: python, eclipse-plugin, set, pydev, list-comprehension

```
{x for x in range(10)}
```

works perfectly on IDLE, but when I try this in eclipse (with Pydev plugin) I get a syntax error:

> Undefined variable: x

Is it because Pydev doesn't support set comprehensions or something? What can I do to make this work?
(This was just one example that doesn't work. All set comprehensions don't work for me).

(I'm using Python 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in PyDev; in this case ignore the editor's warning and execute the code: it will work.

I get this a lot, PyDev isn't perfect but it's good enough!

Comment: Thanks. I don't like getting errors so I won't use the feature. I'll do this instead: set(x for x in range(10))

Comment: shouldn't this have been fixed in version 1.4.3, according to the changelog? If it isn't, maybe we should issue a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Pydev is configured to use Python 3.

Comment: I guess it is configured because I use Python 3 features all the time. But still, how do I check if it's configured to use Python 3?

Comment: Checked. I use Python 3. What else can it be?

Comment: Window > Preferences > Pydev > Interpreter - Python

Comment: When I run this from the shell: {x for x in range(10)},
that's the output: {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

Comment: the syntax error is a warning in the editor or something you get when you run the script from pydev? In the first case, it apparently was a bug in Pydev fixed in release 1.4.3: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2009-February/007246.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which version of Python you are using with

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write( sys.version )
```