# PyDev dict comprehension syntax error python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev

PyDev isn't parsing dict comprehensions for me. I don't really care but it then block code analysis on the rest of the module.

```
foo={x:x for x in range(20)}
```

gives me a syntax error after the :  The error is "Expected:}"

The code runs fine. (it's just a sample!)

I'm running pydev version 3.0.0.201311051910, python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] and eclipse 4.3.1.

I can see there was a fix for this in PyDev 1.6.3 release notes so maybe a regression?

I've also deleted the python interpreter in the preferences and then added it again, no dice.

Thought I'd ask here before adding a bug report.

Comment: An interesting problem - can you please maybe provide a screen shot? or a more detailed error description? (maybe include links to the release notes) - it seems you may have to open a bug...

Comment: Related: [Set comprehensions don't work on Pydev (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576927/set-comprehensions-dont-work-on-pydev-python)

Comment: Screenshot: http://imgur.com/Wzs5xKq

Comment: Check your grammar version in your interpreter setup. Is it 2.7? Sometimes it likes to revert to default. It works for me on the same version of the tool, but 32-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Fenikso answered the question.

Went to Project -> Properties -> PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar and found the grammar version was set to 2.6. Set it to 2.7 and everything works perfectly. Happy days.

http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html